# How to print in a previous console line using python?

Tags: python, console, printf, console-application

Suppose, I have this piece of code:

```
print("1")
print("2")
print("3")
```

Output:

```
1
2
3
```

But my desired output is,

```
1 3
2
```

What should be my code if I want the above output?

Comment: `print("1 3")` and `print(2)`?

Comment: @jizhihaoSAMA No, I want the piece of code to print "3" to be in the third line.

Comment: I think it is a `XY` problem, Do you really need this?

Comment: @jizhihaoSAMA could you please elaborate? I''m a noob in python

Comment: Think it's something to do with sex - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_sex-determination_system . No seriously, it means that jizhihao thinks you are asking about the thing that you think will help you to achieve what you want, rather than the thing that you actually want to achieve - see http://xyproblem.info/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have printed an item, you can't really go back to it. So you are going to need to store the items in memory and then print them when you are ready. For example, you could do:

```
output1 = "1"
output2 = "2"
output1 += " 3"
print(output1)
print(output2)
```

Depending on the number and type of data items, there will be more sophisticated ways in which you could manage this (e.g. list of lists and a function to format them as a string), but the basic principle is that you will need to keep the output in memory until it is ready for printing.

(Note, if you really want to write to exact positions on the screen - in that sense you can "go back" to what you have printed earlier - then you can read about [curses](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/curses.html) programming. But expect this to become quickly **much** more complicated.)

Answer (score -1):

I think you are looking for this :

```
print('1', end=' ')
print('2')
print('3')
```

`end=' '` forces output to end with space instead of line break.

Comment: This doesn't produce the expected output